# Incorrect output for Project Euler #14 output

Tags: java, algorithm, collatz

I'm trying to implement the algorithm to solve [Project Euler Problem #14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), which asks to find a number in a given range that outputs the largest Collatz conjecture sequence length. My code is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Collatz {
    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> previousNums = new ArrayList();
    public static int seqLen(int x) {
        ArrayList<Long> colSeq = new ArrayList();
        long val = x;
        colSeq.add(val);
        while (val > 1) {
            if (val%2 == 0) {
                val/=2;
                if (val < previousNums.size()) /*used to check if index exists*/{
                    colSeq.addAll(previousNums.get((int)val));
                    break;
                }
                else colSeq.add(val);
            }
            else {
                val = 3*val + 1;
                if (val < previousNums.size()) {
                    colSeq.addAll(previousNums.get((int)val));
                    break;
                }
                else colSeq.add(val);
            }
        }
        previousNums.add(colSeq);
        return colSeq.size();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int greatestNum = 0;
        long totalVal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<=1000000; i++) {
            int collatz = seqLen(i);
            if (collatz > totalVal) {}
            greatestNum = i;
            totalVal = collatz;
        }
        System.out.println(greatestNum + " " + totalVal);
    }
}
```

The output I get is

```
1000000 153
```

While this is not the correct answer, 153 is the correct sequence length for 1 million. Based off of this, I could assume that my Collatz conjecture algorithm works, but not the comparison part. However, I can't really find anywhere else I could modify the code. Any ideas? Thank you and please pardon the possibility of this being a duplicate (not many other posts had the same problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, a mere syntax error was the issue. Looks like I didn't pay attention to:

```
 if (collatz > totalVal) {}
            greatestNum = i;
            totalVal = collatz;
```

Yup, didn't enclose the code with the braces.